# Is there any way to hide 3rd-party requests in chromium based browsers?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium, brave-browser

As of now when the `3rd-party request` checkbox is enabled, it **shows** the `3rd-party request`, I want the opposite of it.

There are many request to mixpanel, sentry; which makes it hard to spot the relevant requests.

Since, I've blocked these requests, `Blocked Requests` checkbox could also be helpful, if there was any way to negate it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I guess that typing `domain:*.yourdomain.com` should return almost the same result as an inverse "*3rd-party requests*".
But since you did block these requests, you can actually negate the `Blocked Requests` built-in filter by typing `-status-code:0`.

Comment: wow..thanks. such a relief after all those red coloured rows went away..

Answer (score 0):

**First Solution:**

**Just enter in Filter:**  `url://your-domain.de`

[image]

**Second Solution:
Add Domain Pattern to Ignore List**

[image]